# How can I make loader cover the all page

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are my codes below. I want the loader cover the all page but it just covers the top. How can I make it cover the all page? There are my codes below. I want loader cover the all page but it just covers the top. How can I make it cover the all page?

```css
/*loader*/

.loader-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #333233;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.loader {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 4px solid #Fff;
  animation: loader 3s infinite ease;
}
.loader-inner {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  animation: loader-inner 3s infinite ease-in;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
  25% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  50% { transform: rotate(180deg);}
  75% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
  
}

@keyframes loader-inner {
  0% { height: 0%;}
  25% { height: 0%;}
  50% { height: 100%;}
  75% { height: 100%;}
  100% { height: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<!--loader-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-AFwxAkWdvxRd9qhYYp1qbeRZj6/iTNmJ2GFwcxsMOzwwTaRwz2a/2TX225Ebcj3whXte1WGQb38cXE5j7ZQw3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="loader-wrapper">
  <span class="loader"><span class="loader-inner"></span></span>
</div>

<script>
    $(window).on("load",function(){
      $(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow");
    });
</script>
<!--loader-->
```

Comment: It works for me, showing a full page loader

Comment: Yes the works for me as well. The only difference is that I removed the JavaScript function so the loader does not fadeout.

Comment: try position fixed instead of absolute - it's most likely that in your project the html or body isn't 100% height if it only covers half your screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add position:fixed in main wrapper

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0
```